# Firebase Deployment: My web appear in "project.firebaseapp.com" but not "project.web.app"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I've completely deployed my website with Firebase CLI, and project.firebaseapp.com is accessible and works fine. However, project.web.app keeps showing "Site Not Found".

I'm building my web app with React and already set the folder to "build"

Edit1: I've tried safari, chrome, incognito of both, and also hard refresh and empty cache still showing SITE NOT FOUND.

Edit2: It's working on Line Application Built-in Browser (mobile), but not on Chrome (mobile).

Edit3: Sent the domain to my friends around the world and found out that it's not working for only people living in South East Asia.

Comment: Try accessing it from any other browser.

Comment: I've tried safari, chrome, incognito of both, and also hard refresh and empty cache still showing SITE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Can you share the real link with use? The one that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: [This one is not working](https://covid-test-th.web.app) and [This one works](https://covid-test-th.firebaseapp.com)

I've tested more and found that Singapore/Thailand cannot access to .web.app domain while my Japanese/British/Taiwanese friends can.

Comment: I can confirm that on my side both are working.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, try any other browser. Both the domains are working on my computer. It might just take some time for both to deploy and update the cache.

[image]

[image]

It's usually better to ask someone who stays far from you and maybe has a different ISP to test update website. I sometimes use [`Lighthouse`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) and it turns up even it won't show up on my computer. (Apparently the older version gets cached).

I'd recommend disabling cache from network tab in browser console when in development stage:

[image]

Comment: I've send both domain to my friends around the world and found out that it's not working for people living in South East Asia. I'll try Lighthouse for the test. Thank you :)